# Gnome Screensaver and Xinerama

Tags: linux, gnome, xorg

It will be interesting to see what type of content goes on here compared to SO, anyway ...

Anyone know how to get X11/Gnome screensaver to run across all 3 screens in an Xinerama environment as opposed to single savers per-screen.

Hello to everyone from SO who is on here too!

Comment: @Aiden, did you give the solution a try? Did it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning off clone in your `xorg.conf` file so it looks like this:

```
Option "Xinerama" "on"
Option "Clone" "off"
```

Of course, you must be running the monitors as an extended desktop (one big desktop) rather than 3 seperate monitors.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no preference for this. Each screen simply gets its own screensaver. I kind of like it that way, though. Watching two electric sheep at once is more than twice as awesome.